# Get fb access token using JSON on client side

Tags: php, javascript, json, facebook-graph-api, client-side

How can I retrieve my data using JSON

my sample code

test.js(client side)

```
function(){
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=appid&redirect_uri=http://domain.com/sample/index.php", function(data) {
    alert(data.userName);
});
}
```

index.php(server side)

```
<?php
    $aReturn['userName'] = "carlo2893";
    echo json_encode($aReturn);
?>
```

but it doesn't return any.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you most likely need

1. register your application in http://developers.facebook.com
2. include facebook's init javascript - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
3. once you got access token, you can use it on backend